# Submit form sending through user1_id and newmsg without page refresh

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, forms

How would I go about submitting the below form without a page refresh using Ajax? I'm needing to send the user1_id via 'toid' and the content from the textarea 'newmsg'.

FORM

```
<form action="insert.php" method="POST" class="form_statusinput">
<input type="hidden"  name="toid" value="<?php echo $user1_id ?>">
<span class="w">
<textarea class="input" name="newmsg" id="newmsg" placeholder="Say something" autocomplete="off"></textarea>
</span>
<button type="submit" value="Submit">Feed</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Add an ID to form, lets say "myform".

2) Then you can get all all fields from this form and send it using AJAX (dont forget to include jQuery):

```
        var form_data = $("#myform").serialize(); 
        $.ajax( 
        { 
            url: 'script.php', 
            type: 'POST', 
            cache: false, 
            data: form_data, 
            success: function(message) 
            { 
                ...
            }, 
            error: function(message) 
            { 
                ...
            } 
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

If jQuery is an option, it is quite easy.

See jQuery.post(): http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

```
// Example: send form data using ajax requests
$.post("test.php", $("#testform").serialize());
```

There are many options depending on what you need to do with the return values, it's best to just read the documentation in this case.